# Reuse ReactJS component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, emoticons

I have built a ReactJS component for rendering emoction. Separate component can be built for each emoction, but I want to use one component but pass separate emoction as required.

This is what works so far:

**emoction.js**

```
import { faHeart } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faHeartBroken } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Emoction = () => {    
    return (
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} />
    );
};

export default Emoction;
```

**emoction_hb.js**

```
import { faHeart } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faHeartBroken } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const EmoctionHb = () => {    
    return (    
        // <input type="text" />
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeartBroken} />
    );
};

export default EmoctionHb;
```

Now, I am bundling these two components as:

**expanded_content.js**

```
import Emoction from "../emoctions/emoctions";
import EmoctionHb from "../emoctions/emoctions_hb";
import styled from "@emotion/styled";

import { faHeartBroken } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import React, { Component } from 'react';

const Merged = styled.div`
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: flex-start;
`;

const expandedContent = () => {
    return(
      <div>
        <Merged>
            <Emoction/>
            <EmoctionHb/>
        </Merged>
      </div>
    )
    };
    
export default expandedContent;
```

which when I rendered using **App.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import expandedContent from './components/merged_component/expanded_content'

class App extends React.Component {     
    render(){
        return(
            <Router>
            <>            
            <Route path='/ExpandedContent' exact component={expandedContent}/>
            </>
            </Router>
        )        
    }   
}
export default App;
```

gives me.

[image: bundled emoctions]

What I am trying to do is that instead of creating a component called emoctions_hb.js I want to reuse emoction.js by passing "faHeartBroken" as the value in it. 
If emoction.js is called without any value, I want it to use "faHeartBroken" as default value.

Tried following on to create Parent-Child relationship using https://webomnizz.com/change-parent-component-state-from-child-using-hooks-in-react/ but it did not work out for me.

Comment: *emoction*? I guess you mean *emoticon* ;)

Answer (score 1):

Just pass the icon as a prop and set the default value to `faHeartBroken`:

```
const Emoction = ({ faIcon = faHeartBroken }) => {    
    return (
        <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faIcon} />
    );
};
```

Comment: That seems to help with setting default. How about reusing it with different emoction when called through another component?

Comment: `<Emoticon faIcon={faHeart} />`

Comment: Such a nice solution. I see that ReactJS is so pythonic. :)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're importing `useState` but you're not implementing it anywhere. You could try implementing state in your expanded_content.js file and pass that down to your child component emoction.js, like this:

```
const ExpandedContent = () => {

    const [heart, setHeart] = useState(true)

    return(
      <div>
        <Emoction heart={heart} setHeart={setHeart}/>
      </div>
    )
    };
    
export default ExpandedContent;
```

Notice that you will need to change the name of your component. See the docs here https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html.
Then, inside of your `Emoction` component you will have access to `heart` which is set to true by default and you can also implement some logic to toggle the state using the function `setHeart` which is  passed down from `ExpandedContent`:

```
const Emoction = ({heart, setHeart}) => {
    
    const handleHearts = () => {
        setHeart(heart => !heart)
    }
    return (
       heart ?  <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeart} /> : <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faHeartBroken} />
    );
};

export default Emoction;
```

By using a ternary statement to return your component you can decide to show `faHeart` or `faHeartBroken` depending on the current state. All you need to do is add the functionality wherever you need it.